# Why do I get a wrong result for this calculation in my android app?

Tags: android, double

In my app i am using this to calculate a number:

```
double result = ((a * a) + (b * b) - (2 * a * b));
```

If a for example a = 2 and b = 3.9, then the result should be 3.61. However, when I display "result" i get the number 3.610000000000001.

What is wrong here? How can I correct this error?

Comment: Um, if a = 2 and b = 3, then you've got ((2 * 2) + (3 * 3) - (2 * 2 * 3)) which is (4 + 9 - 12), i.e. 1. Have you missed some code out?

Comment: this is typical with floating point representation. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: (It's almost certain that really the problem is your understanding of floating point numbers, and that using BigDecimal is the answer if you have to have "exact" results.)

Comment: Are you sure the values are being assigned right? Print `a` and `b` first and check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format your output value by using the following construct:

```
String result;
twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
result = twoDForm.format(value);
```

After this, in result you will have your value in X.XX format